# how to find similar (or twin) precipitation stations from the record

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, correlation, missing-data, spatio-temporal

I have precipitation data with some missing values from several stations. I tried to implement IDW to fill missing values. I am looking for some index that could use to select the stations having similar properties (or statistics). I tried with the lowest distance with high Pearson correlation but still not getting a good result. Any suggestion on this problem is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should give some more details, such as patterns of missing? are long blocks of time missing, or only one or a few consecutive points at a time? % missing? Missing at same or different times as other stations? ...

Then, your background, indicating what kind of answer you need. Meteorologist, statistician, other? ...

Back to your question: Maybe correlation by itself between the measurement stations is not satisfactory. The series will probably show seasonality, maybe even different seasonality for different stations, and other systematic effects. That indicates that you want some multivariate spatial timeseries model, and then looking at residuals from that model, and then you could correlate those residuals.  Meteorologists should have knowledge that can be used, directly or as a prior.

What kind of models? Some references that could be useful:  [Modelling Seasonal Behaviour of Rainfall in Northeast
Nigeria. A State Space Approach](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=2ahUKEwjgsJmoza7dAhUKCSwKHTZIBC8QFjADegQIBhAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sapub.org%2Fglobal%2Fshowpaperpdf.aspx%3Fdoi%3D10.5923%2Fj.statistics.20160604.02&usg=AOvVaw0ShlCfeZu6h0Lb98-JHqGR),     [The Kriged Kalman filter](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02565111).   Kalman filters in some version could be useful since they can be estimated also using series with some missing data. They could also be used (after fitting) to interpolate the missing data, that way obliterating your search for a method to fill in data.